# Can Linux be installed successfully on an intel atom D2500/GMA3600?

Tags: linux, video, debian, gpu, intel-atom

I'm triyng to install debian on an intel D2500HN motherboard that features the GMA3600 Power VR video chip. I tested various versions, 32 and 64 bit but the result is always the same: an artifact which takes up a quarter of screen space, located at the bottom of it.

[image]

[image]

Can Linux be installed successfully on this motherboard? (I don't mind if hardware acceleration doesn't work, I just want to see the entire desktop and occasionally some poor quality Youtube video)

Comment: Did you try installing the [GMA3600/PowerVR video driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21938) offered by Intel?

Comment: No, when I searched the Intel site I could find only the Windows XP/7 drivers. (I searched for D2500HN and not Power VR)

Now I'll try the ones you linked, I hope I'll be able to install them.

Comment: As i thought I'm not able to install them. I'm stuck at patching kernel (the first step). I went halfway trough the Debian Linux Kernel Handbook then I got lost, too many confusing options...

Answer (score 1):

I have installed successfully a Lubuntu 12.04 32 bits on a Meteorit netbook using D2500 and GMA 3600.
http://www.pearl.fr/tablettes-mini-pc/notebooks-netbooks/notebook-13_3-meteorit-nb-13-version-160-go_PX9896.html

but others like 14.04 or 15.04 come with graphics issues, I don't know why.

Surprisingly, the touchpad worked during install, but not after anymore. But a USB mouse is ok.

Comment: Can you provide more details here? link only answers become useful if the link breaks some time in the future. Thanks